# Example applications of overloading the assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I hope this isn't seen "primarily opinion based" or "too broad". It's fairly straight forward question:

What are some example problems to which overloading the assignment operator offers a solution?

I don't think I've yet seen a situation in which it would be useful, especially considering the negative implications of having a program full of surprise implicit behaviours and "smoke and mirrors".

Comment: Do types in the Standard Library count?

Comment: Are you asking when you assignment operator should be overloaded ? If yes, check [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: @imreal Sure, can you explain an example?

Comment: @Mahesh I've seen the Rule of Three, but I don't quite understand the (semantic) difference between defining a copy constructor, and overloading the assignment operator.

Comment: You're probably confused by `MyClass c = thing_to_copy;` which calls the copy constructor instead of an assignment operator. If you replace that with `MyClass c; c = thing_to_copy;` you'll get the assignment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
struct X
{
    int *p;
    X(): p{new int[42]}
    ~X() { delete p; }
};
```

What will happen if you do

```
X x, y;
x = y;
```

? The default assignment operator will copy the raw pointer, and you'll end up delete-ing the same pointer twice by the destructors of `x` and `y`. In fact, you'd better declare a copy constructor here too (or, even better, use smart pointers). Note that in

```
X x = some_obj;
```

the copy constructor is invoked (or [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) if the rhs is a prvalue). The assignment operator is invoked only **after** construction, when you say

```
x = some_other_obj; // x is already constructed here
```

If you ask whether the `operator=` should exist at all (in contrast to e.g. Java), then it's probably a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I see. This distinction between when a copy constructor is invoked vs when the assignment operator is invoked is what cleared it up for me.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Glad it helped!